# 'int' object has no attribute 'user_list'. (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a feature where user can remove an item from a list. The code below does successfully remove (delete) the item from the list but also returns the following error (and my AJAX call doesn't complete successfully):

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_list` on serializer `UserVenueSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'user_list'.
```

I am not sure how to debug this/why this error is being thrown.

Here is my serializers:

```
class UserVenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = mapCafesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserVenue
        fields = ['user_list', 'venue']
```

Here is my views

```
class RemoveVenueViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserVenueSerializer
    authentication_classes = [CsrfExemptSession]
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_list = self.request.GET.get('user_list', None)
        venue = self.request.GET.get('venue', None)
        data = UserVenue.objects.filter(user_list = user_list, venue= venue)
        print(data)
        return data.delete()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
<QuerySet [<UserVenue: UserVenue object (142)>]>
Internal Server Error: /api/removevenue/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 457, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 97, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'user_list'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 502, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 190, in get_attribute
    return super().get_attribute(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 490, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_list` on serializer `UserVenueSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'user_list'
```

I'd be grateful for any advice!

Comment: The `get_queryset` is supposed to return a queryset, not delete stuff. Also if that is only supposed to be a view to delete an object, you should use a [`DestroyAPIView` (DRF docs)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview) instead.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying this method but am receiving ``AttributeError: type object 'RemoveVenueViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using vanilla Django and it worked like a charm.

```
def remove_venue_from_list(request):
    user_list = request.GET.get('user_list', None)
    venue = request.GET.get('venue', None)
    data = UserVenue.objects.filter(user_list = user_list, venue = venue)
    data.delete()
    return render(request, 'testingland/index3.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this method**

```
class RemoveVenueViewSet(APIView):
serializer_class = serializers.UserVenueSerializer
authentication_classes = [CsrfExemptSession]

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_list = request.GET.get('user_list', None)
    venue = request.GET.get('venue', None)
    success = UserVenue.objects.filter(user_list=user_list, venue=venue).delete()
    if success:
        return Response("Question deleted", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    return Response("Item does not exixt", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```